# How to make object returned by java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance() to extend other class

Tags: java, interface, encapsulation, extend

```
newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, Class<?>[] interfaces, InvocationHandler h);
```

Returns an instance of a proxy class for the specified interfaces that dispatches method invocations to the specified invocation handler.

I need to encapsulate instance returned by this method (for example,into some other class) so, that it will also extend other class. So the final class will extend one class and implement specified interfaces.

class to extend is:

```
public class IProxy {

ObjectRef oref;

public IProxy(ObjectRef oref) {
    this.oref = oref;
}

}
```

so the process should be :

```
MyInterface() mi=(MyInterface) newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, Class<?>[] interfaces, InvocationHandler h);

// some magic trick
```

and in the end I would like to have instance of class that extends IProxy and implements all interfaces that mi did implement.

Comment: That is not possible. Can you provide more details on why it should extend that class - there might be other ways of achieving what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do it, because the object returned from `newProxyInstance` already inherits from some other class, and you cannot inherit from two classes in Java.

You need to keep `oref` as an instance variable of your class that implements the `InvocationHandler` interface. You will initialize `oref` in the constructor of the `InvocationHandler`, and provide an interface to access `oref` through a method:

```
public interface IProxy {
    ObjectRef getOref();
}
```

Your `InvocationHandler` should respond to calls of `getOref` by returning its `oref` member.

Comment: But even still : how can he implement the interfaces of IProxy without referencing the classloader directly ?

Comment: He wouldn't 'implement' that interface in the Java sense. Rather, it would respond to calls of `getOref` as part of its dispatch routine inside the `invoke(Object, Method, Object[])` method implementation, when it detects that the method being called is `getOref` from `IProxy`.